# CSS problem with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having a problem with margins / line-height in one of our websites.

I am using a Jquery script to create a Drop Cap effect in the first letter of each sections, that adds a class to them. There are two types of dropcaps, as you can see. Google Chrome is not rendering the smaller ones correctly. You can compare with other browser and see the difference.

Any idea about why is this happening? Is there a fix / hack for this?

Comment: if you are doing chrome extensions check out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10910/google-chrome-extensions-webstore?referrer=SDGU8262nOKdp17Pr161Vw2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround would be to set `margin-top:-1px` to the `.dropcap` CSS rule ..

must be some discrepancy on the size the text gets rendered..

Comment: And do you know any hack to target that only to Google Chrome? Thank you!

Comment: @0al0, have a look at http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: I used this solution with the chrome css hack, THANK YOU

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix it by adjusting your `line-height` on your `p` tags.

I adjusted it to 1.8 - anything less and the third line of copy can not flow underneath the drop cap.

See the images:

[alt text http://web17.twitpic.com/img/126705561-f3957c59ceac70c081953d4ce00c9d5e.4c35afb0-full.png](http://web17.twitpic.com/img/126705561-f3957c59ceac70c081953d4ce00c9d5e.4c35afb0-full.png)

[alt text http://web14.twitpic.com/img/126705484-0b710f203011f574c598d698fffce8ab.4c35afb0-full.png](http://web14.twitpic.com/img/126705484-0b710f203011f574c598d698fffce8ab.4c35afb0-full.png)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line-height to 1.8em worked for me. But in general, this problem is very difficult to avoid because fonts are rendered differently across platforms and even across browsers.