# CSS Problem with Chrome and first-letter pseudo-element

Tags: css, solution, pseudo-element

I have a problem where Google Chrome on Windows places the first letter of the paragraph differently compared to all the other browsers such as IE, Firefox, Safari. The difference is in the vertical placement - the letter appears higher in all other browsers (the same way in every one of them) but lower in Google Chrome, making styling the first-letter almost impossible.

Do You happen to know why and how this happens?

Could be that the styling of the mother DIV is affecting the paragraph styling but I do not think so.

Also, by the way, the Drop-Caps plugin in WordPress does not work in Firefox.

Comment: Same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202661/css-problem-with-chrome/3202776#3202776

Answer (score 0):

If you are using relative font sizes (percentage or point based), these are often rendered differently in each browser. See [W3 for more info](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop)